# How to turn on multiselect checkbox mode on a grid in ext js

Tags: extjs, datagrid, extjs4

I am experimenting with this:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/infinite-scroll.html

I'm trying to make it possible for the grid to have checkboxes beside each row, so that a user can select multiple rows.

I tried:

```
SelModel: 'CheckboxSelectionModel',
```

In the configs, it didn't make a difference, I've also removed this line:

```
disableSelection: true,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the selection model class. For example, you can have it in your grid panel's initComponent method:

`this.selModel= Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel');`

or you could add the following into grid's config:

`selModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel')`

If you see the API documentation, the [selModel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-selModel) requires a Object and not a string.

Comment: I like to add, there is a `mode` config for the model to define if it allows single or multiple selection: `selModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {mode : 'MULTI'});` It defaults to `'MULTI'`, I just wanted to point at that.

Comment: Thanks guys, one more thing, how do I get an array of what has been selected?